# Using 127.0.0.1 fails when connecting to MySQL while using IP succeeds using VB.net

Tags: mysql

When trying to connect to MySQL using 127.0.0.1, using vb.net I get the following error message:

"Authentication to host '127.0.0.1' for user 'test' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (Using Password:YES)"

However when I replace 127.0.0.1 with the IP address for the same machine, the connection works perfectly fine.

So what setting need to be changed to solve this issue so that I could use 127.0.0.1?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, change the permissions to allow that user to access via that host in MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each user is related with an IP, and allowed to connect only from this one. Probably your user 'test' is allowed to connect from the 'IP'. And the 'IP' doesn't necessarily translate to '127.0.0.1', even though it is the same machine.

For example using mysql command line add(or similarly with phpmyadmin):

```
create user 'test'@'127.0.0.1' identified by 'your_password';
```

Comment: I replaced the % sign for the user test with 127.0.0.1 and everything worked. Thanks.