# Access Denied for user '' (using password: NO) but it does have password

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, mariadb

I have a trouble accessing the `mariadb` via `visual studio` `vb.net`
I have a working `script` for `mysqlconnectionstring` which I have used from my previous projects which is still running perfectly though. Btw, the `connectionString` I've used so far is somehow similar to this -> [Mysql connectionString](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

But when I use the same connection string for my `document tracking system` for some unknown reason it does throw a pop-up error saying [image]

What surprises me though is that I have change the users and specifically include a password on that one! As per advised of this previous question [Using 127.0.0.1 fails when connecting to MySQL while using IP succeeds using VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740825/using-127-0-0-1-fails-when-connecting-to-mysql-while-using-ip-succeeds-using-vb)

So what could be the reason why I can't connect to this MariaDB server?

I can guarantee you the problem isn't on the insert statement because like I've said the `messagebox` shows the error exception the moment I try to connect to the db server.

But in case you need it for some reference, then I'll place the code here:

```
Dim DatabaseName As String = "myDB"
Dim server As String = "127.0.0.1"
Dim userName As String = "myUsername"
Dim password As String = "myF*ckinPassword"
Dim port As Integer = "3306"
If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()
conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; port={4}; pooling=false", server, userName, password, DatabaseName, port)
Try
    conn.Open()
    'MsgBox("Connected")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    conn.Close()
Finally
    conn.Dispose()
End Try
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

It is also worth to mention that I have included the `Mysql.data.dll` to the `add reference` as well as `System.data.dll` and properly installed all the `connector`, `reader`, and all necessary pre-requisite in case you would ask.

For the meantime, I have already tried a lot of solution-esque I could find in the `IoT`, such as adding new users and re-installing the packages to name a few.

**UPDATE**

I did the common troubleshoot for `Grant all` and `flush privileges` as well as `change ip address` and also the changing of `Listen 80` to `Listen 192.168.0.X:80` etc... etc... but the error remains the same.

I have previous projects which works fine even when I load it on the same `solution explorer` where I've load the `DocumentTrackingSystem` form. Yet it does not get the same error. I have also try testing it to another computer, but the problem remains the same.

It's as if I could not connect to `mariadb` for as long as I am connecting through this project.

New Mugshot:

[image: Figure2]

[image: Figure3]

[image: Figure4]

[image: Figure5]

[image: Last]

[image: Call Stack]

[image: DotNet Version]

[image: Maria DB Version]

**LATEST**!

I have no clue as to why it can't detect my `connectionString` no matter how I try to fix it, the error remains the same. I decided to somewhat merged it to a previous working project which is a Library Management System.

So basically, what I did is that, I created another form and included it on the list of menu. I am just at the design phase though. But when I run the whole program, it didn't show up!

View in the `Formnew.vb Design`
[image: Spook1]

View as soon as I run the program
[image: Spook2]

It is just a plain `label` but why it didn't show the way it is suppose to? It is not hidden, and I haven't include any codes yet. It is just a simple `label`.

Comment: I'm not sure that you're using a valid connection string for Connector/Net. Try [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/).

Comment: Dear, if you have saw the link I have shared in the first paragraph of this question, you may see that's exactly where I got my connectionString from. Still, thanks though.

Comment: Then why is it that every example there uses "Uid" and "Pwd" while your code uses "user id" and "password"? The fact that you are using the wrong names for those attributes would explain why the error message indicates that you haven't provided a user name.

Comment: Sweetie, those actually work in my other projects. And those are called variables. Nevermind the naming because that is not my concern. Just please pay attention to the origins of my question and the pop up window because that error seemingly off. Eventhough I've re-installed `xampp` twice for that. It says `access denied (using password: no)` though I am calling a username with a password on. Anyway, thanks for the effort and for trying to answer my question. I appreciate that.

Comment: What type of object is con? Try adding the port to the server variable and remove it from connectionstring, like "127.0.0.1:3306". Also using a ConnectionStringBuilder-class should be preferred.

Comment: I did what you've said, @Esko. But nothing has changed. It displays the same error. I've uninstalled and installed `VS2019` and re-installed the `mysql` packages but it just remains the same. What makes it more weird is when I load my old project which has the same `connectionString` and `references` and it still working! But why the heck is this one?!

Also, the `conn` object is my variable for the new `mysqlconnection`

Comment: @Archangel08 Can you get the full errormessage (with innerexceptions and stacktrace) by replacing ex.Message with ex.ToString() and add it to your question? Also add the generated connectionstring as it is now.

Comment: I just did @Esko. Please see the `New Mugshot`

Comment: @Archangel08 Your password is empty, why? And that seems not to be full errormessage in the first picture, there is no stacktrace visible. This seems very confusing to me.

Comment: @Esko, I have also tried to install the db to another server computer which where I previously installed a super working project. But the error remains just as it is as seen in the last image. Confusing? I know right. I don't know what could be the cause of it. I've tried a lot of troubleshooting cases but nothing seems to fade this error away.

Anyone please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; port={4}; pooling=false", server, userName, password, DatabaseName, port)
```

will produce a connection string which is not valid according to the [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) link you posted.

It outputs

```
server=127.0.0.1; user id=myUsername; password=myF*ckinPassword; database=myDB; port=3306; pooling=false
```

The field names (user id and password specifically) are wrong. See this demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2QDJNY

Try this instead, which matches the format provided on the connectionstrings site:

```
String.Format("Server={0};Port={4};Database={3};Uid={1};Pwd={2};Pooling=False;", server, userName, password, DatabaseName, port)
```

This will output:

```
Server=127.0.0.1;Port=3306;Database=myDB;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myF*ckinPassword;Pooling=False;
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hlAVYf

Comment: Can you please tell me the _exact_ error message you get now you've changed the code?

Comment: And...this is hopefully a silly question, but can you also confirm there's nowhere else in your code where you also try to make a connection? Hopefully not, as that would be duplication, but it's worth checking that the error is actually coming from where you think it is. It might be worth logging full exceptions and stack traces to a log file (as well as just popping up a message box with the basic details) so you can get the full picture of the exception including line numbers etc.

Comment: please check the last screenshot above. I have placed it there since yesterday. That's the exact error I encountered after I followed your instruction. Also this is a`VB.Net` project we're dealing with. I've noticed in your example that you're using `C#`.

Comment: No I'm not. All the code above, and the dot net fiddle links, are VB. Check them carefully. If it was c# you'd see `;` at the ends of each line above. And the fiddle links are very clearly VB. But the concept would be the same either way, the connection string is identical no matter which language you use

Comment: As it happens, this line of code is basically identical in both languages anyway

Comment: Anyway, the problem is bizarre. It seems not to be detecting any of the parameters in the connection string. Can you please a) log the full exception and stack trace and post it in the question. b) tell us the .NET version you're using, the version of the mysql connector/NET library, and the version of mariaDB you're connecting to. c) shows us your app.config for this project. Thanks.

Comment: P.P.S. you mention you've got other projects where this problem does not occur. Have you tried simply creating a brand new project in Visual Studio and adding your code there, to see if it reproduces it? Just in case the project is somehow corrupt (I don't know how, but VS can occasionally behave badly). If you get it working then you can just copy/paste all your other form code etc into the new project. It might be easier than trying to debug this.

Comment: please see the last 3 images of the screenshot section. As you can see the `Call Stack` are clean. Also, I'm using all the latest version of `.Net connector` and everything. Plus my `Xampp` (`MariaDB`) is in latest version.

As per your advice, I did try to merge this project on the previous one working (by calling a different `DB` ofcourse), but to no avail. I don't know what the heck is happening on this d*mn thing. Its been 11 days already, but am still stuck on the same issue. Please, help me identify the cause.

Comment: From that screenshot, you seem to have MySQL Server installed, not MariaDB. Are you sure you haven't got them _both_ installed and running? Maybe it's not connecting to the database instance you think it is

Comment: I'm sorry but I see no difference in `MariaDB` and `MySQL` when it comes to `connectionString` though. If so, why is it that the other projects I used this code with works really well, apart from this one?

Comment: Do they definitely specify the same host, username and password in your other applications? You're right there's no difference in the connection string but if you have a copy of mysql and a copy of mariaDB running on the same machine then they will be accessible on different ports and have different usernames and passwords available

Comment: It makes no sense that one project would behave differently to the others unless there's a material difference in the code and/or variables it's using to make the connection

Comment: P.s. can you put your whole project code files online somewhere downloadable (or at least a version which contains this login code and nothing else, if the rest is private)? I think I'm going to have to see if I can reproduce this on my own machine

Comment: P.P.S. can you also tell me the version of Visual Studio and the version of Xampp. I can see your MySQL is version 8, but I can't see your Xampp or MariaDB version.

Comment: Pardon me, @ADyson, but I couldn't expose this project online because of the client agreement. However, you can just copy the code I've screenshot.

Also, the `Xampp` version is shown in the last screenshot of the above questionaire. And its 7.3.31

Comment: I'm not re-typing it by hand from a screenshot sorry...lol. You could at least paste the code so I can copy it in one go. Don't make it hard/boring for people to help you!  Besides I want to see the project references, build definitions etc, if you claim it's the project which is faulty, and not the code. Like I said, you can share the project files and the code files relevant to the database connection, and remove anything which is private

Comment: Also you still didn't tell me the visual studio version. P.s. xampp is definitely not shown in any of your screenshots (all the items mentioned on the last screenshot are mySQL)  but thanks for telling me

Comment: P.p.s. why did you even install xampp? Seems you aren't going to use the Apache or PHP parts? MariaDb can be installed separately, and you've already got mysql installed anyhow so not even sure you need it

Comment: Honey @ADyson, thank you for your help. I really appreciate it but it seems you and I are from a different page. Anyways, I really appreciate you. Plus, please look closely because I can still see the `Xampp` below the `MySQL` list.

Also, everyone knows that Xampp runs both `Apache` and `MySQL` so I don't know why have you ask about not using `Apache`.

Comment: you know I think my browser must have cached the question page. Now it shows the picture. Sorry. I am asking about not using Apache because you're building a .NET desktop application, not a PHP web application. So you don't need a webserver like Apache for that. Your desktop application connects directly to the database, it does not use the webserver. And Xampp runs MariaDB, not MySQL. (https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html). So if you installed Xampp, you must have installed MariaDB as well. That's why I'm talking about you having both of them installed, why you need that?

Comment: Anyway let's stick to the point, and share me your code. Thanks.

Comment: please read and check my **latest** post. I have encountered yet another weird stuff when I decided to add another `Label` inside the menu of an existing working project. For the sole purpose of loading the DTS thru this working one once I put the `call function`. But before I could do so, the computer start acting weirdly again. I don't know why even. The `Label` itself, isn't showing when I run the program. it is just a plain Label. why on earth it hid when running? No code were added just to make it hidden.

Comment: Since you provided no code I can't possibly tell you where might have gone wrong. And "acting weirdly" could mean anything, no idea what that could be. I don't know what the "call function" is, or means, or how it relates to your label either. This information is, at best, unclear, and at worst a complete diversion from the original issue. Like I said to you before, until I can get hold of some actual code including the proj file etc, a version which causes the error you're talking about, I really can't help you any further. I made that clear in my previous comments.

Comment: If you are unable or unwilling to do that, then I'm afraid there is nothing more I can do for you, sorry. P.S. I'm afraid you also don't help yourself by being vague about requested info, providing seemingly irrelevant info instead, and ignoring some questions entirely. That's a separate issue, I guess, but it means it will be easier for me to just get hold of the code myself and try it out than attempting to get any further debugging information by this method.

Comment: I don't get it when you said I did not provided a source code when it is clearly shown in the pictures. Honestly, I noticed that you hardly look on them coz you keep on asking questions where it is already clearly stated in the images above. So why keep on asking about the errors message, the installer version and the source code if you can just view it yourself?

Does your image viewer work well? If not, then I would understand. No need to be harsh. Hahaha

Comment: I didn't say you didn't provide _any_ source code. I said you didn't provide _enough_ code to be able to see the issue. The code you've shown doesn't, by itself, cause the problem you're describing. I was asking for more source code. You declined to provide it. I already apologised for not checking your post carefully enough on a couple of occasions. But I was also trying to double check all my assumptions because it's a weird error. I wanted to see the project files etc to see if that's the issue, since you said it only happened in certain projects. But you never provided anything like that.